# Inner join in mysql take a long time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table contacts with more than 1,000,000 and other table cities which have about 20,000 records. Need to fetch all cities which have used in contacts table.
Contacts table have following columns
Id, name, phone, email, city, state, country, postal, address, manager_Id
cities table have 
Id, city

I used Inner join for this, but its taking a long time to go. Query takes more than 2 minutes to execute.

I used this query

```
SELECT cities.* FROM cities 
INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.City = cities.city
WHERE contacts.manager_Id= 1
```

created index on manager_Id as well. But still its very slow.

Comment: Indexes on the `city` fields could be more helpful, but really, `contacts` should be referencing `cities.id`, rather than `cities.city`; for faster integer comparisons.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the cities fields?

Answer (score 1):

for better performance you could add  index

on table cities column `city`

on table contacts a composite index  on columns `(manager_id, city)`

Comment: @MarlinPierce  . could be ..  answer  updated ..  thanks

Comment: thanks, but issue is contacts table having almost 20 column and 5 single columns already have indexed, and 2 composite index, is it will be prefer to use many indexes on a table

Comment: You should eval the query you really need  to improve performance and the query most used and apply the indexes  based on these evaluation  ..  .. for improve performance in sql you need  index ..  but you must balance the number of indexes respectec  your real needs

Comment: @MarlinPierce, Can you please also explain, how having manager_id first should be faster?

Comment: @user3337590  .. the use of manager_id  as first column in index  ins related  to the fact you have a literal value in your where clause  ..  in this case the mathcing between  where clause and the index  content can reduce the number of row scanned  in the index  and improve performance  (hope my comment is clear)

Comment: @AnkitBajpai user3337590 and DRapp explained.

Answer (score 1):

Filter `contacts` first and then join to `cities`:

```
SELECT ct.* 
FROM cities ct INNER JOIN (
  SELECT city FROM contacts
  WHERE manager_Id = 1
) cn ON cn.city = ct.city
```

You need indexes for `city` in both tables and for `manager_id` in `contacts`.

Comment: Do you think that instead of having 2 different Indexes on city and manager_Id on contacts table, having only 1 composite index as (city, manager_Id) would be better?

Comment: No, not in this case.

Comment: May you please explain the reason for the same?

Comment: An index for manager_Id is needed for the filtration of contacts (WHERE manager_Id = 1). The other 2 indexes in each table for the join ON cn.city = ct.city. I don't see for this query the need for a composite index.

Comment: A composite index (manager_Id, city) could be better. However, the only real way to tell is to try both solutions and compare the output of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...`

Comment: thanks for helping, its much faster with composite index (manager_id, city) on contacts table only, but if use 2 different index for single column then its not much faster

Comment: @user3337590 for my query and for filtering the contacts table: where manager_id = 1, the composite index is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out about having proper index, I am taking it a bit more for clarification.  You are specifically looking for contacts where the MANAGER ID = 1.  This is not expected to be one person, but could be many people.  So having the MANAGER ID in the first position will optimize get me all people for that manager.  By having the city as part of the index via (manager_id, city), you are pulling the two data elements you need to optimize as part of the index.  This way the engine does not have to go to the raw data pages to get the other part of interest.

Now, From that, you want all the city information (hence the join to city table on that ID).

Since you are only querying the CITIES and not the actual contact people information, you probably want to have DISTINCT City ID.  Lets say a manager is responsible for 50 people and most of them live in the same city or neighboring.  You may have 5 distinct cities?  That too will limit your result set of joining.

Having said that, I would do a follows, and with MySQL, using STRAIGHT_JOIN can help optimize by "do the query as I wrote it, don't think for me".

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
      cty.*
   from
      ( select distinct c.City
           from Contacts c
           where c.Manager_ID = 1 ) PQ
         JOIN Cities cty
            on PQ.City = Cty.City
```

The "PQ" is an alias representing my "pre-query" of just DISTINCT cities for a given manager.

Again, have one index on Contacts table on (manager_id, city).  On the city table, I would expect and index on (city).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add two indexes, one on `cities.city` and one on `(contacts.manager_Id, contacts.city)`. That should speed things up significantly.

Comment: The index should be based on the qualifying component.  In this case contacts with a specific manager.  The city is just a come-along for result set.

Comment: @DRapp yes, you are right. I've updated my answer. Maybe I was just a little too fast when answering. Then again, a simple query like this, even with those table row counts, should not take 120 seconds. Not even 120 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need two indexes, one on each table.

On the `contacts` table, first index `manager_Id`, then `City`

```
CREATE INDEX idx_contacts_mgr_city ON contacts(manager_Id, City);
```

On the `cities` table, just index `City.

Comment: thanks, but issue is contacts table having almost 20 column and 5 single columns already have indexed, and 2 composite index, is it will be prefer to use many indexes on a table

Comment: For this query, if you have an index on `(manager_Id, City)` this query will not make use of any other index.  *(The indexes might be used for other queries, however.)*

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'City' field from the table 'Contacts' a VARCHAR?

If that's the case, I see multiple things here.
First of all, since you have already have the 'Id' for the corresponding city in your 'cities' tables, I don't see why not to use the same 'Id' from the 'cities' table for the 'Contacts' table.

You can add the 'IdCity' field to the 'Contacts' table so you don't have to modify your existing records.
You'll have to insert the 'IdCity' manually though for each of your records, or you can create a Query using 'cities' table and then compare the 'idCity' but insert the 'city' (city name) in your 'Contacts' table.

Returning to your query:
Then, use an INT JOIN instead of a VARCHAR JOIN. Since you have many records, this can show up an important significance in performance.